# In java, about access modifiers, what the word "world" means?

Tags: java, modifiers

I've seen here on stackoverflow a post where there was this simple and clear summary about access modifiers in java.
I understand all but just one thing is weird :what the word "World" stands for ? What does it mean?

I have delete the display of the schema summary because the render was weird :s
So please look at the link below >>>

Here is the link of the post:
[In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Thks in advance!

Comment: It just means it is visible to everyone.

Comment: World visibility is non-reflective visibility into the package.

Comment: Yes, i was wondering it is possible to see the source code of java app ? if yes how ?  So it means that if i don't want people to see it i have to make the access protected, is that right?

Comment: That is an entirely different concern than the one access modifiers address!

Comment: "World" is a bit of an aberration.  For decades this concept has been known as "global".

Comment: Thks all, i understant now the global meaning/concept of world.

Comment: @HotLicks, the difference between world readable and global scope are rather important - global has taken on very negative meaning, while world readable is important for published API methods.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni - In other words, "world" is used to obfuscate what's going on.

Comment: @hotlicks it's assigning a descriptive label to describe the meaning of public, I don't think that can be quantified as an obfuscation.

Comment: Introducing a second word that means the same as the first one does not add clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if I have a class like:

```
package com.example;

public class Foo {
    public int bar;
}
```

I can access it from "outside" in the most general meaning of the word, like:

```
package com.client;         // not in the same package of `Foo`

class Client {              // not a subclass of `Foo`
    Foo foo = new Foo();    // possible because `Foo` is world-visible
    public int foobar() {
        return foo.bar;     // possible because `bar` is world-visible
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, thank you i understand better, but how do you know it is"world-visible" ? since i can't see the word "world", but maybe i think that by default, if i don't specify, then the class method or variable would implicitely be "world-visible" ?

Comment: It's because of the keyword `public`. The default is actually package-visible.

Answer (score 0):

"World" is the visibility description when using non-reflection references from outside the package, as in a library reference.

Comment: Thks understand better world meaning now.

Answer (score 0):

World means you can call that method, or access that field or class no matter where the code is written, no matter the packaging, subclass, and so forth.

It could even be "universe" if you prefer.

Comment: Thks, understand better the concept now.

Comment: @HotLicks You could if you had an instantaneous communication layer (ICL) with an asynchronous socket protocol. Don't leave home without one.

Comment: The problem is that Beta Tauri 5 uses a base pi numbering system.  They have most of the translation worked out, but they frustratingly can't translate `1`, and `1` is the value of the `public` modifier.